# What would be a beginner's book on radiative transfer?

Tags: resource-recommendations, atmospheric-science, radiative-transfer

I want to learn the basics of radiative transfer for my reasearch, which is on planetary sciences. I am looking for a book that would give me the basics of radiative transfer (the mathematics involved) so that I can perform numerical modeling of the radiative transfer process in planetary atmospheres and upper surfaces. I started with the book [Spectroscopy and Radiative transfer of Planetary Atmospheres](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073QW56S5), but I feel it is a bit to difficult for me to catch up. I need something like a primer on this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chandrasekhar's book is anything but suitable for beginners.

Rob Rutten's course on radiative transfer is classic in the field of stellar atmospheres. It is available here:
https://robrutten.nl/rrweb/rjr-pubs/2003rtsa.book.....R.pdf

Dullemond's course covers slightly different areas and it is more introductory:
[https://www.ita.uni-heidelberg.de/~dullemond/lectures/radtrans_2017/](https://www.ita.uni-heidelberg.de/%7Edullemond/lectures/radtrans_2017/)

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, one suitable book for beginners is the S. Chandrasekhar's books called Radiative Transfer (1960). Basic concepts and derivations are very well explained. Again, this is my opinion :).